# Parent child forms - child form shrinks on maximize and restore down

Tags: c#, winforms, parent

I have a winform and opening other forms inside this using IsMdiContainer property. In contructor of parent I got :

```
    this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

then for child I got :

```
        child.MdiParent = this;
        child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

for some reason if you maximize and restore down(not minimize) the child form shrinks each time. Now in child form I have a dock.fill panel and two groupboxes one docked to top and other dock to fill.

any ideas why this behaviour is happening?

Thanks

Comment: The child form *has* to shrink down in order to fit in its new (smaller) container.

Comment: but how would i make the parent to stop getting smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't happen. Check the code for your child form and see if you can find any additional size settings.

Comment: Then I guess it's somehow related to the contents of groupBoxes. AutoSize of groupBoxes are set to true maybe? or the contents change their size and force the container to expand or shrink unexpectedly?

Comment: found the solution had to set a minimum size for the parent form. as it was set to 0 by default it shrunk it to that :)